# Finding a constant in a joint PDF with constraints on $x$ and $y$

Tags: probability, integration, statistics

Given the PDF $f(x,y) = cx$

$0 \le x \le y \le 1  $

What would my bounds of integration be? Both $x$ and $y$ are dependent on each other so I'm not sure how to do this without getting an equation including both c and a variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can translate the inequality directly into the limits of integration:

$ 0 < x <y$ becomes $\int_0^y dx$ and $0<y<1$ becomes $\int_0^1 dy$